# Matching data from two tables with unequal number of rows

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have 2 tables, and I am trying to match up the data but all the answers have suggested right joins or full joins, which are not available on SQLite.

```
Table 1: 

╔═════════╦═════════╦══════╗
║ Company ║ Product ║ Cost ║
╠═════════╬═════════╬══════╣
║ A       ║ abc     ║  100 ║ 
║ B       ║ abc     ║  150 ║
║ F       ║ xyz     ║  250 ║
║ G       ║ xyz     ║  300 ║
╚═════════╩═════════╩══════╝
```

However I have a list of more companies (with same products)

```
Table 2:

╔═════════╦═════════╗
║ Product ║ Company ║
╠═════════╬═════════╣
║ abc     ║ A       ║
║ abc     ║ B       ║
║ abc     ║ C       ║
║ abc     ║ D       ║
║ abc     ║ E       ║
║ abc     ║ F       ║
║ abc     ║ G       ║
║ xyz     ║ A       ║
║ xyz     ║ B       ║
║ xyz     ║ C       ║
║ xyz     ║ D       ║
║ xyz     ║ E       ║
║ xyz     ║ F       ║
║ xyz     ║ G       ║
╚═════════╩═════════╝
```

How do I match them up so they look like this?

```
Table 3:

╔═════════╦═════════╦══════╗
║ Product ║ Company ║ Cost ║
╠═════════╬═════════╬══════╣
║ abc     ║ A       ║ 100  ║
║ abc     ║ B       ║ 150  ║
║ abc     ║ C       ║ null ║
║ abc     ║ D       ║ null ║
║ abc     ║ E       ║ null ║
║ abc     ║ F       ║ null ║
║ abc     ║ G       ║ null ║
║ xyz     ║ A       ║ null ║
║ xyz     ║ B       ║ null ║
║ xyz     ║ C       ║ null ║
║ xyz     ║ D       ║ null ║
║ xyz     ║ E       ║ null ║
║ xyz     ║ F       ║ 250  ║
║ xyz     ║ G       ║ 300  ║
╚═════════╩═════════╩══════╝
```

When I use this code,

```
SELECT Company, t.Product, Cost
FROM table1 as t INNER JOIN table2 as f ON t.product = f.product
WHERE t.company = f.company
```

it only returns [Company] with an associated [Product] and [Cost], but does not return [Company] with null values.

When I use

```
SELECT Company, t.Product, Cost
FROM table1 as t INNER JOIN table2 as f ON t.company = f.company
```

then my output looks like

```
╔═══════════╦═══════════╦═════════╗
║ t.Company ║ f.Company ║ Product ║
╠═══════════╬═══════════╬═════════╣
║ A         ║ A         ║ abc     ║
║ B         ║ A         ║ abc     ║
║ F         ║ A         ║ abc     ║
║ G         ║ A         ║ abc     ║
║ A         ║ B         ║ abc     ║
║ B         ║ B         ║ abc     ║
║ F         ║ B         ║ abc     ║
║ G         ║ B         ║ abc     ║
║ A         ║ C         ║ abc     ║
║ B         ║ C         ║ abc     ║
║ F         ║ C         ║ abc     ║
║ G         ║ C         ║ abc     ║
╚═══════════╩═══════════╩═════════╝
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite *does* support `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, which should do the job just fine:

```
select two.product, two.company, one.cost from two 
 left outer join one on 
   ((one.company = two.company) and (one.product = two.product));
```

(where `two` is your "table 2" and `one` is your "table 1")

Running this in SQLite with the above data:

```
abc|A|100
abc|B|150
abc|C|
abc|D|
abc|E|
abc|F|
abc|G|
xyz|A|
xyz|B|
xyz|C|
xyz|D|
xyz|E|
xyz|F|250
xyz|G|300
```

Comment: I didn't even think I could join on multiple columns (i.e., ((one.company = two.company) and (one.product = two.product));). Total newbie mistake! Thanks for so much for your help!